# Why is this infinite $digest loop error taking place?

Tags: angularjs

I cannot figure out why I am getting an infinite $digest loop error in this simple demo. I've read about these loops in the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig), but I don't understand why this demo triggers the error.

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/stamminator/pen/mRWoNx)**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var TestApp = angular.module("TestApp", []);

    TestApp.controller("TestCtrl", function ($scope) {
      $scope.Counter = 0;
      $scope.IncrementCounter = function () {
        $scope.Counter+=1;
        return true
      }
    });
</script>
<body ng-app='TestApp'>
  <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <label>
      Number of times <code>$scope.IncrementCounter()</code>
      has been invoked: {{ Counter }}
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ IncrementCounter() === true }}" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there no way to increment a `$scope` variable from within a `$scope` function without causing the whole model to go through a digest cycle?

Comment: Oversight on my part. I've fixed it to just return a boolean, but that was an unrelated issue. Issue still persists.

Comment: @AlonEitan Instead of a downvote (if that was you, if not, no worries), I'd appreciate a critique or a solutions, as the Stack Overflow guidelines indicate.

Comment: I've upvoted to prove it wasn't me who downvoted - Try to avoid calling a function in an angular expression, To debug this - Delete the `{{ IncrementCounter() === true }}` part and see if the error still happen

Comment: @AlonEitan Much appreciated.

Comment: Please re-read my comment, im not sure if you noticed my suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133680/discussion-between-jacob-stamm-and-alon-eitan).

Comment: I'm using mobile device so i can't have a chat at the moment. Sorry :(

Comment: No worries, we'll chat here. Yes, the error stops if I remove that section, but it's that very functionality which I need to work. From all documentation I've seen online, calling a function from an angular expression is perfectly valid.

Comment: Please read the grat answer posted by @Matthew it explain the issue you're having well. Sorry for being rude in my first comment

Comment: You can also read [this](http://railsguides.net/fix-angular-digest-iteration-errors-with-memoization/) to better understand the issue with your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you were calling the `IncrementCounter()` function from within a binding in the view. In a `$digest` cycle Angular looks at the `{{ }}` brackets and executes any functions held within them, your `IncrementCounter()` function happened to change a value on the scope `$scope.Counter`, and this in turn kicks off another $digest cycle, and so the process repeats continually.

You should do all of this in the Controller and only use the view for displaying values held on the scope. You could for example do this using a function that calls itself, optionally using the $timeout service to create a delay:

```
var TestApp = angular.module("TestApp", []);

TestApp.controller("TestCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout) {

  var init = function() {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    incrementCounter();
  };

  var incrementCounter = function () {
      $scope.counter++;
      $timeout(function() {
          incrementCounter();
      }, 1000);
  };

  init();
});
```

With the above code your view can then be:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Function Invocation Tester</title>
  </head>
    <body ng-app='TestApp'>
      <h2>AngularJS Function Invocation Tester</h2>
      <div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
        <label>
          Number of times <code>$scope.IncrementCounter()</code>
          has been invoked: <span class="counter">{{ counter }}</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really get at the heart of the issue. First, even if I take my `Counter` variable out of my `$scope`, the issue still takes place (in fact, in [this modified demo](https://codepen.io/stamminator/pen/MJpdrQ), the issue actually doubled!). In addition, what I'm really trying to debug here is having scope function calls inside angular expressions, which I've gotten to work plenty of times in the past without infinite loops. What is causing either of these demos to kick off the infinite loop?

Comment: It's because you're changing the scope on this function call. If you comment out `//$scope.Counter+=1;` as so, it will run without $digest error. It's won't work (increment the counter), but it will run, proving the cause of the problem.

Comment: Please see the demo I linked in my comment. I moved my counter variable *outside* of the scope and the issue is still taking place.

Comment: You make a good point, and I had to question myself. I now believe that the error isn't specifically because the scope has changed, but because of how $watches work. When you use the {{ }} brackets you create a $watch and so angular is watching/listening for change to the return value of your `IncrementCounter()` function. [It's explained here in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

Comment: `The listener is called only when the value from the current watchExpression and the previous call to watchExpression are not equal` so because the return value of your IncrementCounter() function is changing after every call, it continually executes $digest cycles.

Comment: @JacobStamm has this answered your question?